# Redactor 2 error 'accessibility-help-label'

Tags: redactor

I made the update for Redactor 2 and I'm getting this error:

```
VM463:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'accessibility-help-label' of undefined
```

Can anyone help? I can't find the problem.

Comment: When you say "I made the update for redactor 2" what does that mean? Did you update from Craft < 2.5 to Craft >= 2.5 or something else? Try doing a manual update and clear Craft's and your browser's caches? craftcms.com/docs/updating#manually-updating

Comment: i already found the problem, the problem was that i was calling a language 'pt_pt' that there wasn't no translations, then we got this problem... the translations are for pt_br, that was the difference.
Thanks.
Carlos Vieira

Comment: Ahh, glad you're all sorted.  Would you mind adding that as an official answer in case someone else runs into the issue?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is set the right translations... the problem was using translations "pt_pt" instead of "pt_br".

Take care of using the right translations